# Python moving files between different folders

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7

It is ment to go through my 1TV directory and move and rename the files it finds. Move each file it finds into a folder with the show name and then the season. The files are to be renamed with Show + episode + file extension. I am manually adding the file extension at the moment as I am still testing my code. I wil as so tidy it up.

The problem is I get a error when I try and move the file

```
!!! .DS_Store Can't handle !!!
Elementary/S01/Elementary14.mp4
TypeError: "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'exceptions.IOError' objects"
```

I have handled the .DS_Store file as I am on a mac. but the TypeError I do not understand why I get that have tried changing my code around making the string in the call before etc. No luck

```
#Rename files
#NAME.S##.E##.QUALITY.USER.FILETYPE

#Elementary.S01E15.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4
#Greys.Anatomy.S09E13.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4

import os
import shutil

def checkCreateDir(f):
    if not os.path.exists(f):
        os.makedirs(f)

#Main LOOP
for filename in os.listdir("./1TV"):
    try:
        firstDot = filename.index('.S')
        name = filename[:firstDot].replace("."," ")
        season = filename[firstDot+1:firstDot+4]
        episode = filename[firstDot+5:firstDot+7]

        #File movement
        checkCreateDir(name)
        checkCreateDir(name+"/"+season)
        newFilename = name+"/"+season+"/"+name+episode+".mp4"
        print newFilename
        shutil.move(filename,newFilename)

        print name + "\t"+ season + "\t" + episode
    except ValueError:
        print "!!! " + filename + " Can't handle !!!"
    except IOError as detail:
        print "IOError " + detail
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. BTW: This is a very raw version I will tidy up once I get it running some what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate the `IOError` exception to the string `"IOError "`. Just use a comma instead:

```
print "IOError", detail
```

which will include the word `IOError` already, so a simple:

```
print detail
```

should suffice.

You probably are getting `IOError`s because you are using relative filenames, but your source files are listed in a subdirectory; `os.listdir()` lists only the base filenames, directories are *not* included.

Use `os.path.join()` to construct paths instead, string formatting for other strings:

```
checkCreateDir(name)
checkCreateDir(os.path.join(name, season))
newFilename = os.path.join(name, season, '{}{}.mp4'.format(name, episode))
print newFilename
shutil.move(os.path.join('./1TV', filename), newFilename)
```

Comment: Got it to work thnx heaps btw the newFileline & 2nd checkCreateDir is missing a closing ) I fixed them up

Comment: Thanks heaps, Also for the explanation I can see where I went wrong now to tidy up the code :p